# Exception Error Handling in python spits out error after specifying not to

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, error-handling, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to stop this code from giving me an error about a file I created called beloved.txt I used the FillNotFoundError: to say not to give me the error and to print the file thats not found but instead its printing the message and the error message. How can I fix it ?

```
def count_words(Filenames):
    with open(Filenames) as fill_object:
        contentInFill = fill_object.read()

    words = contentInFill.rsplit()
    word_length = len(words)
    print("The file " + Filename + " has " + str(word_length) + " words.")

    try:
        Filenames = open("beloved.txt", mode="rb")
        data = Filenames.read()
        return data
    except FileNotFoundError as err:
        print("Cant find the file name")

Filenames = ["anna.txt", "gatsby.txt", "don_quixote.txt", "beloved.txt", "mockingbird.txt"]
for Filename in Filenames:
    count_words(Filename)
```

Comment: What is the output and error you are getting?

Comment: And add the full traceback of the error, so we (and you) can see which line raises the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few tips:

- Don't capitalize variables besides `class` names.
- Use different variable names when referring to different things. (i.e. don't use `Filenames = open("beloved.txt", mode="rb")` when you already have a global version of that variable, **and** a local version of that variable, **and** now you are reassigning it to mean something different **again**!! This behavior will lead to headaches...

The main problem with the script though is trying to open a file outside your `try` statement. You can just move your code to be within the `try:`! I also don't understand `except FileNotFoundError as err:` when you don't use `err`. You should rewrite that to `except FileNotFoundError:` in this case :)

```
def count_words(file):
    try:
        with open(file) as fill_object:
            contentInFill = fill_object.read()
        words = contentInFill.rsplit()
        word_length = len(words)
        print("The file " + file + " has " + str(word_length) + " words.")
        with open("beloved.txt", mode="rb") as other_file:
            data = other_file.read()
        return data
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Cant find the file name")

filenames = ["anna.txt", "gatsby.txt", "don_quixote.txt", "beloved.txt", "mockingbird.txt"]
for filename in filenames:
    count_words(filename)
```

I also do not understand why you have your function `return data` when data is read from the same file regardless of that `file` you input to the function?? You will get the same result returned in all cases...

Comment: So the suggestions worked I just confused myself because I was referring to that file globally and locally and that meant the error code will be posted more than once. I did remove the return the data part because its repetitive.  Thanks Reedinationer

Comment: @abdullahalhamidi No problem! Glad to help :) If this solved your problem you should click the check mark by my post to mark the thread as solved.

Answer (score 0):

The "with open(Filenames) as fill_objec:" sentence will throw you the exception.
So you at least must enclose that sentence in the try part. In your code you first get that len in words, and then you check for the specific file beloved.txt. This doubled code lets you to the duplicated mensajes. Suggestion:

```
def count_words(Filenames):
    try:
        with open(Filenames) as fill_object:
            contentInFill = fill_object.read()
        words = contentInFill.rsplit()
        word_length = len(words)
        print("The file " + Filename + " has " + str(word_length) + " words.")
    except FileNotFoundError as err:
        print("Cant find the file name")
```